# Mapbox Map does not load

Tags: android, mapbox, http-status-code-401

Even though I am using Style.LIGHT which is free, I get "loading style failed: HTTP status code 401" error.

I use an active access token, no whitspaces.
The code did work fine yesterday, all of a sudden android crashed. Maybe because of Instant Run which is now disabled.

Also, I get this:"Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (light greylist, reflection)"

[Code where I initialize the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msgYn.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfduJ.png)

[new error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5SZY.png)

[Mapbox map loaded ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTWWL.png)

my token I have copied to my strings.xml

I don't know what else to check and would be happy about any hints.

Comment: Did you check if your access token is still valid? They expire.

Comment: I just created the token today, so it should be valid I guess...

Comment: Access tokens don't necessarily expire unless you explicitly rotate them. But a  `401` status code is very likely being caused by either an invalid token, or a token that is not being set properly. Can you please share an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your map code (without pasting your token) to help us understand what might be going on?

Comment: Any update on this issue? Maybe a missing char while copy pasting the token?

Comment: I have added some more information, hope this helps, if you need anything else, I'll do my best :)

Comment: Also, I've discovered a new error meassage in my logcat:
"IOException while requesting key:  Invalid device key response"

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured out what caused the http error:

I have included my token via strings.xml
Somehow the compiler confuses the order and tries to load the map code before embedding the string value.

However, if I directly insert the token, everything works perfectly fine :D

Hope I could help some of you guys!